# Design of collections in a generic card game library

Tags: oop, collections

I want to implement a library for card games of all types. I found out that OOP would probably the best way to implement such a library. So I started with modelling of some classes for UI (which has concrete subclasses ConsoleUI, SDLUI, HTMLUI), Party (with the subclasses Player and Group), Card, CardAttribute, Turn, TurnCommand, CompoundTurnCommand. Those classes are as good as complete.

But now I detected that there are several different kinds of collections of cards. I thought to create an abstract class CardCollections with many subclasses:

```
CardCollection = abstract collection of CardCollections
Card = a single card
Hand = an indexed random access list. If you execute draw(index), all CardCollections after index are shifted left (like a linked list)
Tablet = an indexed random access list. If you execute draw(index), the CardCollections after index are not shifted, can contain gaps between cards (like an array/dictionary)
Pile = an LIFO collection (like a stack)
Stock = a FIFO collection (like a queue)
Row = a double-ended collection (like a deque)
Random = a non-indexed undordered collection (like a bag)
```

Because I want to follow common OOP design practises, like inheritance and polymorphism, I am looking for a proper model - and here the problem begins.

I started to create interfaces for all concrete classes:

```
ICard extends IHand and ITablet.
IHand extends IRandom and IRow.
ITablet extends ICardCollection.
IPile extends ICardCollection.
IStock extends ICardCollection.
IRow extends IPile and IStock.
IRandom extends ICardCollection.
```

But I am very unsure about the design because it requires many, many interfaces.

Is there a better and more proper way for this? Because the library should be independent of the programming language I don't expect concrete implementations.

Comment: "the library should be independent of the programming language" - can you elaborate that? Most languages already HAVE some collection APIs, containing exactly the collections that you mentioned (LinkedList, Stack etc). Are you going to offer your library for different programming languages (with *the same class names* )?

Comment: I thought about an API especially for easy-to-learn languages like Tcl, Smalltalk or Lua. It should be as easy as possible to the user to implement cards games without any programming skills. Unlike the standard collection classes like Java Collections  the focus are card games. Therefor methods like Pile.draw() or Stock.discover() are more suitable here.

Comment: are these for playing cards (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_card) or can there be some other types of cards?

Comment: @Ray Tarak: There can be any type of cards - CardAttribute and TurnCommand are very flexible.

Comment: @Marius Spix see edit to my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is certainly not an acceptable answer, and maybe even subjective, but ... too long for a comment, and maybe it encourages others to give more profound answers:

It's difficult to give design hints as long as the description is so vague in terms of programming language and intended usage. E.g. I'm not entirely sure whether you mentioned `Card` as one of several `CardCollection`s - intuitively, a single Card is no collection of cards. Additonally, in your description, you talked about `CardCollections` where I had expected only a `Card` (e.g. "*...all CardCollections after index are shifted...*" - shouldn't this be "*...all **Cards** after index are shifted...*" ?)

However, I think the decision about the precise inheritance relationship mainly depends on the *methods* that these classes will contain, and how they are intended to be used. Given the limited information, my "generic" approach would roughly be the following:

1. Insert all methods that you'd expect in the respective class. A first guess:

   ```
   CardCollection  {
       int size(); 
   }

   Hand {
       Card draw(int index);
   }

   Tablet {
       Card draw(int index); 
   }

   Pile {
       void putFront(Card card);
       Card takeFront();
   }

   Stock {
       void putEnd(Card card);
       Card takeEnd();
   }

   Row {
       void putFront(Card card);
       Card takeFront();
       void putEnd(Card card);
       Card takeEnd();
   }

   Random {
       ???
   }
   ```
2. Factor out common parts. This might be tricky. It already depends on whether the language of choice supports multiple inheritance or things like `interface`s in Java. More importantly, it depends on whether the language supports *non-public* inheritance. For example, when you write `class ExtendedClass extends BaseClass` or `class ExtendedClass implements BaseInterface` in Java, then this is set in stone. Everybody who uses the API will rely on this inheritance, and it can never be changed after the first release. In contrast to C++, where you can write `class ExtendedClass : private BaseClass` and the user of the API will never know that you inherited from `BaseClass`. (I'm not familiar with Tcl, Smalltalk or Lua, so I can't say anything about that - and for sure, C++ is the best example for a **not-so**-easy-to-learn language ;-)).
3. Construct an inheritance hierarchy based on the common parts. This *could* for example be according to what you already described, e.g. `Row extends Pile and Stock`. Alternatively, you could classify the classes according to what they allow you to do, possibly in some abstract form that is possibly not even directly visible to the user:

   ```
   // Private part:
   FrontQueue {
       void putFront(Card card);
       Card takeFront();
   }
   EndQueue {
       void putEnd(Card card);
       Card takeEnd();
   }

   // Public part:
   Pile extends FrontQueue {}
   Stock extends EndQueue {}
   Row extends FrontQueue, EndQueue {}
   ```

Of course, this once more depends on the language and the intended usage. One would also have to ask whether these classes should rather serve as a "facade", and the actual behavior should be implemented via composition instead of inheritance. An obvious example for a further questions is: Should every method that expects a `Pile` also accept a `Row`? Alternatives for the class design might also be considered. For example, instead of letting `Row` inherit from `FrontQueue` and `EndQueue`, one could declare

```
Row {
    FrontQueue getFront();
    EndQueue getEnd();
}
```

Again, these are just thoughts, and in the worst case, not answering your question, but instead raising new questions, but ... maybe the ones that you have to answer on the way to your goal anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

your design has already been done a few times. except for card, all of your interfaces are very similar to collection, list, queue, stack, and deque. there are the [java collections framework](http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~pearce/modules/lectures/j2se/jcf/jcf.htm), the [c# collections framework](http://codeidol.com/img/essential-csharp/michaelis_fig12_07_alt.jpg), and [dart](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch03.html#ch03-collections). you will probably come up with something similar.

i would suggest a spike using concrete implementations where everything extends collection, list, queue, stack, or deque then refactor out whatever interface hierarchy that you can find.

edit: i just noticed that you have: ICard extends IHand and ITablet. card is probably it's own interface. something like:

```
enum Type {poker, tarot, magic ... }
interface {
     Type type();
     Map<String,Object> attributeNameToAttributeValue();
}
```

you could have sub interfaces for card flavours like:

```
enum Suit { clubs, diamonds, hearts, spades }
enum Rank { deuce,trey,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,jack,queen,king,ace }
interface PokerCard extends Card {
     Rank rank();
     Suite suit();
}
```

Comment: I don't use inheritance in this case. Cards simply have an array of CardProperties, e. g. (Smalltalk syntax):

    jackOfHearts := Card new: #(jack hearts)